# Russian equivalent of the superlative expression “even in the most peaceful of regions"

Tags: грамматика

> Even in the most **peaceful** of **regions**, something happens."

```
one indefinite, unspecified region, the most peaceful one imaginable out of all regions
```

To express the idea of "something being the case even in the most extreme circumstances", in English you usually use the construction "the most + peaceful(singular) + of + regions(plural)".

Now I wonder how you idiomatically say this in Russian. Should both "мирном" and "краю" be in the singular? Or is it more common to use some other *singular-plural* combination?

> Даже в самом **мирном** **краю** ...

Comment: As shown below, the question of which part to be expressed in the singular or in the plural varies from language to language. In French: "Même dans les **régions** les plus **paisibles**, ...", both being in the plural. In German: "Selbst im **Ruhigsten** aller **Länder**, ...", with the singular and the plural being mixed.

Comment: I think it would help if you would explain the context some more. "Even in the most peaceful land" what?

Comment: @yury10578 Actually, it can be virtually anything, as I'm not talking about any specific context here. So I left it blank. "*Even in the most peaceful region, you might see a bar fight or two every now and then*" -- you name it.

Comment: You may use both plural and singular here, because neither is a frequently used expression. Unless you are speaking of a land in geographical sense, you shall better use "в тихом месте" (only singular). Sounds more idiomatic to me.

Comment: Of Russian "ready-made" idioms I can only think of "Раз в год и палка стреляет" which shares some remote resemblance.

Comment: @Alone-zee you example of a bar fight seems to me the opposite to your abstract (and undecipherable practically, for me ) explanation "something being the case even in the most extreme circumstances". Here it is more like "something *extreme* (bar fight) being the case even in the most *non-extreme* (peaceful region) circumstances",

Comment: There seems to be no "really idiomatic" expression for that, then, and the literal Russian translation is already in the answers.

Comment: I'd like to throw in the word `наиболее`.

Comment: For a while I was hesitating whether to make pun or not, but whatever, let it be. Just for the sake of a joke. "Даже и в самом тихом омуте....." :-D

Answer (score 4):

Your rendering is correct. Plural can also be used

> Даже в самом мирном **из <sup>out of</sup>** (всех) краёв...

constructed virtually identical to the English  `most peaceful [out] of [all] regions`

This form is less common than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both plural; "*(даже) в самом мирном из краёв*"; and singular: "*(и) в самом мирном краю*", only the form with plural **might** be bit more loaded **emotionally**.

Like, with singular you're telling that something (bad) might happen (even in the most peaceful... etc.). And you'd rather use plural to exclaim: "(to think that) something like this should happen! (in the most peaceful... etc.)".